# Howerive vector stream network from a DEM using D-Infinity Flow Direction algorithm?

Tags: dem, hydrology, flow-accumulation, flow-direction, stream

I have been working with a 1m LiDAR derived DEM to create a vector stream network. Using the D8 flow direction, D8 flow accumulation, and a specified threshold, I was able to create a vector stream network. I used the [Stream to Feature](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/stream-to-feature.htm) tool from ArcGIS Desktop using the D8 Flow Direction raster and the Stream Source Raster. However, if I want to calculate the stream feature from D-Infinity flow direction and flow accumulation, what can be done? In terms of using the Stream to Feature tool of ArcGIS, it does not take the D Infinity Flow Direction raster as input since it is a floating point raster.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1 and also I am using TauDEM software.

Comment: Delineation of hydrological flow characteristics from a 1m DEM is a notable scale mismatch. At that scale you are functionally routing flow around irrelevant obstructions such as stumps and boulders. The idea behind DEM conditioning is to produce a smooth surface. The amount of noise in a high-res lidar DEM will produce somewhat erroneous results as a function of the algorithms and the functional scale that flow operates on. For D-inf you will need TauDEM.

Comment: Actually I am considering this manmade artifacts. I know the high-res DEM would result in erroneous pits and create unnatural flow. However, in TauDEM there is a function called "Stream Reach and Watershed" which also create vector stream line. But it takes the D8 flow direction raster as input in this function. Considering I am interested in D infinity, I still do not know how to get the vector stream network?

Comment: I have used TauDEM, with D-inf, many times for stream delineation. I suggest that you read the command line users guide. http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/TauDEM53CommandLineGuide.pdf